# Firebase Search query

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to search from firebase where the name contain that character from search box at any position in the name? any one help me please 
just like this

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = 
myRef.orderByChild("from").contains(searchText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform contains query in firestore, you can only perform equals to query in firestore, if you want to perform contains query you need to integrate with [Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search#solution_algolia)